# Getting Tried to register widget with id==grid but that id is already registered on My Dojo Grid

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have created a Dojo Grid that returns results from a .Net WS based on search criteria from the browser. The grid works fine the first it is populated, but if I make another search attempt. It throws the following error

Tried to register widget with id==grid but that id is already registered

I understand what the error means, it means that the ID has already been built and cannot be built again, but I have no idea how to fix it.
Here is my JS Code

var grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
                        autoWidth: "true", structure: gridLayout,
                        store: store, clientSort: true
                    }, "grid");

The HTML

What do I need to to the last property of the grid (ie the "grid" part) to make this error go away. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to reuse the widget but replace its data via [`dojox.grid.DataGrid.setStore()`](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/api/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html#setStore). Related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194673/dojo-dojo-data-itemfilewritestore-slow/3197164#3197164).

Comment: Currently I am using 
 store = new dojox.data.ServiceStore({ service: service.serviceName });

to create my store, and use grid.setQuery to fill my grid with my service object. Are there other options that fit more with my structure?

Comment: is right—you should simply be changing the data in the store. You don't want to re-initialize the DataGrid each time you load the data.

Comment: I am confused. What should I be doing to just repopulate the store instead of restarting the Grid.